# When does $8n\log_2(n) = 2n^2$

Tags: logarithms

What is the most systematic way to do this problem? I used the definition of logarithms and brute force to find $n = 16$, but I feel as though that was the worst way possible.

Comment: what $\log$ it is?

Comment: The base is 2 .

Comment: Equations that have both $\log n$ and $n$ in them are usually not solvable without brute force. This one you can simplify to $4\log_2n=n$, but after that, you're out of luck.

Comment: Assuming $n\neq 0$, you may simplify by dividing both sides by $8n$ and then take base 2 on both sides to get $n = 2^{\frac n4}$. To my knowledge there is not much more you can do here. A graphical solutuion or a guess + showing that its the only solution would do it.

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions or any positive real solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dividing by $n$ (and thereby removing the solution $n=0$) and simplifying, we get
$$
-\log(n)e^{-\log(n)}=-\frac{\log(2)}4
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
n
&=e^{-\operatorname{W}\left(-\frac{\log(2)}4\right)}\\[6pt]
&=-\frac4{\log(2)}\operatorname{W}\left(-\frac{\log(2)}4\right)
\end{align}
$$
For negative arguments, Lambert W has two real branches giving two solutions: $1.2396277295227621418$ and $16$.

Answer (score 2):

write your equation in the form
$$n\left(4\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}-n\right)=0$$
you can choose a numerical way or the LambertW function.
$$n_1=-4\,{\frac {{\rm W} \left(-1/4\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)}{\ln 
 \left( 2 \right) }}
$$
$$n_2=-4\,{\frac {{\rm W} \left(-1,-1/4\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)}{\ln 
 \left( 2 \right) }}
$$
$$n=0$$ is impossible

Comment: Don't you think that $-4\,{\frac {{\rm W} \left(-1,-1/4\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)}{\ln 
 \left( 2 \right) }}$ is a really complicated way of writing $16$?

Comment: maybe, you have right

Comment: This is a good answer (and the one I was writing up, but he beat me to it). The point is that $W$ allows you to solve the equation fully, without needing to resort to other heuristics. It's easy enough to evaluate $W$ and get 16.

Comment: ok you are welcome, i don't want to beat you, we all should help to solve mathematical Problems from others

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would think one could also call $n=0$ a solution, because of $\lim_{n\to0}n\log_2(n)=0$. But discarding this solution and recalling that the question was whether we can do without brute force, let me suggest to divide the equation by $8n$ which gives $\log_2(n)=n/4$.  Antilog leads to $n=2^{n/4}$. Raising to the power 16 finally leads to $n^{16}=16^n$. This makes it quite obvious that $n=16$ is a solution, albeit not the only one.